# Why won't Razor parse this in html mode?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm making a reusable package and in order to get the client side to work both with straight javascript and module loaders I have a code paths that requires me to `document.write` out script tags.

In my razor view I have something like this:

```
<script>
   ...
   document.write([
       '<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Oaf/SlimHeader/Media/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>',
       '<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Oaf/SlimHeader/Media/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>',
   ].join('\n'))
   ...
</script>
```

Which Razor refuses to interpret in html mode:

> Parser Error Message: Unterminated string literal.  Strings that start
>   with a quotation mark (") must be terminated before the end of the
>   line.  However, strings that start with @ and a quotation mark (@")
>   can span multiple lines.

indicating the error is in the first script tag. This is javascript, I don't want Razor involved at all! (Ok, it would be nice if it parsed the `~` but honestly I can take care of that myself).

I've tried prefixing every line with `@:` and surrounding the whole thing in `@" ... "@` but neither seems to work.

Comment: I can't see any issues with your Razor. Rather this all looks like pure HTML which shouldn't be parsed by the Razor engine. I rather expect the issue is else where. Try putting JUST that code you have above into your view and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks @Aron paring down actually led me to the surprising answer (below) and possibly a Razor bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Aron who got me to pare this down thereby prompting me to discover the answer.

Pared down the broken code looked like this (I hadn't included the `if` in the question):

```
@if (true) {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var a = '<script></script>';
    </script>
}
```

something in the interplay between the `@if` and the `<script>` tag in a sting just does not sit well. If I force text mode on each line inside the `if` by prefixing with `@:` then it works.

In the original question the solution it to prefix **every** line inside the Razor block with `@:`. Surrounding in a `<text>` block *will not work*. If you don't prefix *every* line with `@:` then you will get a parsing error very possibly for a line that *was* prefixed.

Seems like a bug with Razor. Will report it.

Comment: This looks like an addition to your question, and not an answer.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker absolutely, please don't upvote. This is what solved the problem for me though and is a situation I can imagine other people running into and finding this helpful.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a razor issue, this code is invalid even in a simple HTML file, and will cause problems in the browser.

The solution is to:

```
var a = '<script><' +' /script>';
```

The bug has been closed as by design.

Comment: Yup, see the accepted answer. [I did create a bug on the asp.net mvc bugtracker](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1838) about the confusing error message though.

Comment: George, we just closed the bug. And the accepted solution although *might* work (I didn't check) is incorrect in general because the issue is also appearing in any HTML file.

Comment: Right. There is an additional error that happens in browsers. The question was however specifically about how to get past the Razor error (since I ran into that before I ran into the browser error). I commented on the bug further. Perhaps I was unclear that my complaint was specifically with the error message, not the behavior.

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeMauer I'm going to take a second look at the bug. 

Either way, this answer is what a user should really do to fix the issue (and not the selected answer).

Comment: Fixed the issue, it will be available in the next nightly build on https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetwebstacknightly

Comment: Hey George the fix in now public RTM, thanks for pushing for this!